# No Maps Location Detected on Android Emulator or Device?

Tags: android, maps

I have created an application to detect the users current location and plot it on a map on android - but when I run it on an emulator or device I receive the error "No location detected".

It worked fine previously strangely, I can't think of anything I've changed.

In my OnCreate():

```
  if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
```

I also have the permissions defined in the manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I have pretty much followed this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Can anyone offer a suggestions on what could fix this?

Answer (score -1):

The android emulator doesn't provide any location, as it doesn't have any sensors to pickup a location. Depending on your needs (and emulator), there is some different ways of setting the location. You can easily google them.

Comment: Tried it today on a OnePlus 2 running Android 6.0.1 and no luck either, still the same message.  Locations etc. were turned on.

With regards to the emulator, I have tried changing the GPS co-ords via Android Device Monitor, but it won't let me edit the details.